# A polynomial problem related to $P(x) = 5x^{2015} + x^2 + x + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

Got stuck with this.Can't understand how the given polynomial relates with the question.Any suggestions appreciated :)

> $$P(x) = 5x^{2015} + x^2 + x + 1$$
>
> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial as defined above with the roots of $P(x)$
>   being $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_{2015}$. Find the value of:
>
> $$\left(\prod_{i=1}^{2015} (1+x_i)\right ) \left(
>  \sum_{i=1}^{2015} \frac{1}{1-x_i} \right ).$$

Comment: @graydad $(1+x_i)$ are root of P(x-1)  and $(1-x_i)$ are root of P(1-x)

Comment: Trying to use  Remainder-Factor Theorem interpretation of polynomials...@graydad but im stuck

Comment: Just making sure you've done your HW, so to speak ;) You should include that information in the body of your question

Comment: Hint: write the polynomial $P(x)$ as a formula in terms of the $x_i$ and compare with the given expressions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have:
$$ P(x) = 5x^{2015}+x^2+x+1 = 5\prod_{i=1}^{2015}(x-x_i) \tag{1} $$
from which:
$$ P(-1) = -4 = -5\prod_{i=1}^{2015}(x_i+1) \tag{2}$$
and $\prod_{i=1}^{2015}(1+x_i)=\frac{4}{5}$. On the other hand, if we differentiate both sides of $(1)$:

$$ P'(x) = 10075 x^{2014}+2x+1 = 5\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2015}\frac{1}{x-x_i}\right) \prod_{i=1}^{2015}(x-x_i)\tag{3} $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{2015}\frac{1}{1-x_i}=\frac{P'(1)}{P(1)}=\frac{5039}{4}\tag{4}$$
and:
$$ \prod_{i=1}^{2015}(1+x_i)\sum_{i=1}^{2015}\frac{1}{1-x_i} = \color{red}{\frac{5039}{5}}.\tag{5}$$